# I use CollapsingToolbar but it is not working?

Tags: android-viewpager, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I want to use CollapsingToolbar but I have used two AppBarLayout. Technically it's working  but it is not scrolling?? Why it is not scrolling?

I think it's because of LinearLayout. But if it is not there then other ViewPager and Tablayouts are not getting displayed. Please help me.

Notice; I used CollapsingToolbarLayout instead of Toolbar. I don't want to use ToolBar.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/analayer"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">




    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:id="@+id/appbardeneme"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp" >

            <!--<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>-->

        <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/playerframe"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:clickable="true">

            .....
            .......
            ....


        </FrameLayout>




        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabGravity="fill" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:id="@+id/appbardeneme2"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp" >

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabGravity="fill" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how to use a Collapsing Toolbar then please refer to this [link.](https://medium.com/ribot-labs/exploring-the-new-android-design-support-library-b7cda56d2c32#.3vr3r67j7) Here you will get the idea how to use **CoordinatorLayout** with **AppBarLayout** to get a Collapsing Toolbar. Hope it helps you. :)